# Generating Dummy Dataset in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 1D data with a length of around 1000 items. How can i generate Multiple copies of similar looking data which follow the same pattern as the Real data.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some noise like `(np.random.rand(1000) - 0.5)` or `np.random.normal(size=1000)` to your data. You can also tune the magnitude of the change by multiplying or dividing the noise by a constant.